# Add Blog Categories to site Search refiners in SP2013

Tags: search-results, blog, refinement-panel

Client would like to further refine search results that include blog posts by selecting a Blog Category name(s) refiner.

Search results include blog posts now, my question is: How can I add the additional refiner.

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The default Blog site uses a lookup field called "PostCategory". (This is a crappy old approach, they should use MMS.) There is no default Managed Property for the crawled property ows_PostCategory, so you'll need to map that to a Refinable property. Depending on whether you are an administrator you can do this in the SSA or in the search site collection. Once you have performed another full crawl of the blog content you can add your new Managed Property as a refiner to the search results refiner web part.

Comment: On SP2016 Enterprise on-premise, I find neither "PostCategory" nor "ows_PostCategory". I have a hard time locating to which crawled property the "Category" column is mapped.